# Disable any key on the keyboard notebook

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, acer, lts, aspire

**Can I disable the SysRq PrtSc button?** I am using OS xubuntu 18.04 LTS.
My PrtSc SysRq button is stuck, sometimes it pushes itself. So many screenshoot windows appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
xev -event keyboard
```

and hit the key you want to get the key code, and then use

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode [yourKey]='
```

to disable it.

for example :

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 13='
```